# JQUERY, AJAX -- My <tr> isn't removed

Tags: html, ajax, custom-data-attribute

I want to and remove a tr when I click a button, but it doesn't disappear (my function to delete it from the DB works fine, it just stays in the screen until I refresh).

It's like it doesn't take the ID properly.

Any hints?

HTML

```
 <tbody> 
     <?php foreach ($elementos as $elementos): ?>
     <tr class="tr_test" data-id="<?php echo $elementos['ELDI_Id']; ?>">
     ...
```

AJAX

```
 $.ajax({
          url: $("#base_url").attr("valor") + "diccionarios/eliminar_elementos_diccionario",
          type: 'POST',
          data: { id:id_eldi },
          success: function(response){
   // THIS WORKS FINE, BUT I'M ASKED TO DO IT THE OTHER WAY
          /* $(el).closest('tr').fadeOut(800, function(){ 
               $(this).remove();
          }); */

          $('tr[data-id="' + id_eldi + '"]').fadeOut(800, function(){ 
                        $(this).remove();
           });     
      }
});
```

Thanks for your time!

### EDIT

Populated table's html, as asked in a comment:

```
<section class="content">
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="block-header">
        <div class="alert alert-info">
            <strong>
                Elementos del Diccionario 2                </strong>
            <!-- <strong>
                Elementos del Diccionario                </strong>  -->
        </div>    
    </div>
    <div class="row clearfix">
        <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
            <div class="card">                   
                <div class="body">
               <!--  <div>
                    <a class="nav-link" href="http://localhost/bpg/diccionarios/nuevo_elemento_diccionario">Añadir elemento</a>
                </div> -->
                <!-- BOTÓN AÑADIR ELEMENTO MODAL -->
                    <a title="Añadir" style="margin-bottom:20px;" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#Modal_Add">
                        <i class="material-icons">add</i>Nuevo elemento  
                    </a>
                    <div class="table-responsive">
                        <table id="tabla-elementos" class=" display table table-bordered table-striped table-hover tabla-usuarios">
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th>Key</th>
                                    <th>Display</th>
                                    <th>Acciones</th>
                                    <!-- <th>Acciones</th> -->
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody> 
                                                                        <tr class="tr_test" data-id="347">
                                        <td>prueba_1</td>
                                        <td>Prueba Uno</td>
                                        <td>
                                            <span class="btn btn-default editar_elemento" id='347' value="347">
                                                <a href="http://localhost/bpg/diccionarios/elemento_diccionario/347" title="Editar">
                                                    <i class="material-icons">edit</i>
                                                </a>
                                            </span>
                                        <span class="btn btn-default borrar_elemento" id='347' value="347">
                                                <i class="material-icons">delete_outline</i>    
                                            </span>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                                                        <tr class="tr_test" data-id="348">
                                        <td>prueba_2</td>
                                        <td>Prueba Dos</td>
                                        <td>
                                            <span class="btn btn-default editar_elemento" id='348' value="348">
                                                <a href="http://localhost/bpg/diccionarios/elemento_diccionario/348" title="Editar">
                                                    <i class="material-icons">edit</i>
                                                </a>
                                            </span>
                                        <span class="btn btn-default borrar_elemento" id='348' value="348">
                                                <i class="material-icons">delete_outline</i>    
                                            </span>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                                                        <tr class="tr_test" data-id="351">
                                        <td>prueba_3</td>
                                        <td>Prueba Tres</td>
                                        <td>
                                            <span class="btn btn-default editar_elemento" id='351' value="351">
                                                <a href="http://localhost/bpg/diccionarios/elemento_diccionario/351" title="Editar">
                                                    <i class="material-icons">edit</i>
                                                </a>
                                            </span>
                                        <span class="btn btn-default borrar_elemento" id='351' value="351">
                                                <i class="material-icons">delete_outline</i>    
                                            </span>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                                                        <tr class="tr_test" data-id="353">
                                        <td>prueba_4</td>
                                        <td>Prueba Cuatro</td>
                                        <td>
                                            <span class="btn btn-default editar_elemento" id='353' value="353">
                                                <a href="http://localhost/bpg/diccionarios/elemento_diccionario/353" title="Editar">
                                                    <i class="material-icons">edit</i>
                                                </a>
                                            </span>
                                        <span class="btn btn-default borrar_elemento" id='353' value="353">
                                                <i class="material-icons">delete_outline</i>    
                                            </span>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                                                </tbody>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                    <a href="http://localhost/bpg/diccionarios/lista_diccionarios">Volver a Diccionarios</a>
                </div>                                                                               
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: can you also add an example of the table's html after it gets populated?

Comment: I edited the answer, don't know if you meant that.

Comment: I've created a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/k0da5hcb/) and your js code works fine. If you `console.log(id_eldi);` inside the success function do you get the correct value?

Comment: Try swapping your quotes in the JQuery e.g.: $("tr[data-id='" + id_eldi + "']"). So swap single quotes for double quotes and vice-versa.

Comment: I found the problem guys, I'll add the solution. Thanks all!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

### SOLUTION FOUND

I wasn't assigning data-id to the new appended rows.

### JQUERY/AJAX

Fade and remove the tr:

```
$("tr[data-id-fila="+theID+"]").fadeOut(800, function(){ 
                            $(this).remove();
                        });
```

New appended row (AJAX gets result from model and controller using insert_id())

```
var html = 
                    '<tr data-id-fila="' + result.newID +'">'+
..............
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if it's the cause of your problem, but your HTML/PHP is incorrect, it should read:

```
 <tbody> 
     <?php foreach ($elementos as $elemento): ?>
     <tr class="tr_test" data-id="<?php echo $elemento['ELDI_Id']; ?>">
     ...
```

Answer (score -1):

try add it's table parent as identifier:

```js
$('button#btn').on('click', function() {
  $('table#table tr[data-id="1"]').fadeOut(800, function(){ 
    $(this).remove();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="table">
  <tbody>
    <tr data-id="1">
      <td>row</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<button type="button" id="btn">
  remove
</button>
```

only using `tr[data-id=""]` might be too broad for the DOM to find that element.

Comment: Nothing... It only works if I reload the page, not when I add and "draw" a new tr without refreshing.

Comment: well, you didn't tell if you added the element dynamically. how should i know if you did it correctly. maybe you should double check your question later. anyway, it solved and all is good.